# How input parameter in String?

Tags: java

I want put value of a at `{0}`. With C#, I code as:

```
String a="123"
String b="Xin chao: {0}, ban the nao";
String c=String.Format(b,a);
```

But in Java I don't know. Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java's counterpart is [`java.text.MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) that allows placeholders like the one in your question can be replaced using format method as

```
String a = "123";
MessageFormat.format("Xin chao: {0}, ban the nao", a);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String b= "Xin chao: %s";
String bF = String.format(b,"123");
```

Comment: [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) is a static method.

Comment: Yes i forgot it and i have modified my answer right now. thanks

Answer (score 2):

See [`String.format(String format, Object... args)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

For instance

```
String s = String.format("Xin chao: %1$s", "123");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know where the `{0}` will appear, you can use `String.replaceAll()` method:

```
    String a = "123";
    String b = "Xin chao: {0}, ban the nao";
    String c = b.replaceAll("\\{0\\}", a);
```

You might want to check [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) to do automatic escaping.